# Spring integration tests with cucumber won't share state between step definitions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, cucumber-java

When we work with integration tests using Guice we can make use of the @ScenarioScoped annotation to make objects shareable across the lifecycle of a given scenario.
Is this possible to achieve the same with Spring integration tests with Cucumber?

As the example below:
PS: This is not my real code so please avoid comments about quality, etc.

```
Scenario: Status endpoint replies OK
  When I call the status endpoint
  Then response status code is 200
  And response body contains 'OK'
```

The step definition classes look like:

```
public class StatusStepDef extends MyAbstractSpringTest {
   @Autowired private MyHttpClient httpClient;

   @When("^I call the status endpoint$")
   public void callStatusEndpoint() {
       httpClient.callStatusEndpoint();
   }
}

public class HttpCommonsStepDef extends MyAbstractSpringTest {
   @Autowired private MyHttpClient httpClient;

   @Then("^response status code is 200$")
   public void responseStatusIsOK() {
     assertThat(httpClient.getLastResponse().getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()).isTrue();
   }

   @Then("^response body contains '(.+)'$")
   public void responseBodyContains(String bodyText) {
     assertThat(httpClient.getLastResponse().getBody()).isEqualTo(text);
   }
```

}

So I'll get an NPE in the HttpCommonsStepDef class as Spring will inject a new instance of the MyHttpClient making the last response attribute null instead of keeping the same one as the StatusStepDef. Thus again my questions is: How could I share the HttpClient object accross the step definitions for a given scenario?

Comment: Have you tried with Picocontainer?

Comment: It must be Spring DI

Comment: Shouldn't `HttpCommonsStepDef` extend `StatusStepDef`? They are entirely different classes, why are you expecting to have the same client autowired to them? You could do that without changing inheritance, but it would require messing with spring DI mechanisms, I think.

Comment: I recommend you raise an issue with Cucumber team here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm